# Is There A Customizable User-Defined Button Tray?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, shortcut, customization

Does Blender have a built in tool, or is there an addon (or addon/ui designer) that would allow me to have a button tray with user-defined buttons?
Basically I would like to have a tray with specific actions and functions, for example a button to automatically boolean subtract and apply instead of having to go through menus or shortcuts, a button to align selected to Y-0, etc.
Shortcuts are difficult for me to use (and sometimes impossible), so a way to make my own GUI panel with a selection of any of Blender's actions would be greatly helpful.
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will try them.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is- you're looking for the Quick Menu, which is accessible with Q. Right Click on any function and you'll see an "Add to Quick Menu"- choose that and it'll add.

The Quick Menu is unique per view, so you can have different shortcuts in Object vs Edit mode, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in tool that would allow you to build a customized button tray.  As far as I know, there is no add-on that would allow you to generate buttons into a tray the way that [Quick Favorites](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html#quick-favorites) allows you to add menu entries to a favorites menu.

If you can tolerate having a single shortcut (default <kbd>Q</kbd>) to bring up a menu to select from, then Quick Favorites might do for your purposes.

The next closest thing available is an add-on that allows you to use a node system to build your own scripts.  [Serpens](https://blendermarket.com/products/serpens) is a paid addon that is meant to be used to quickly script things like your button tray, but does require you to do some scripting via its node system.

The usual approach for building custom trays like this would be to do your own add-on, customizing the tools to your purpose.  There is a tutorial, [*Scripting for Artists*](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/) from the Blender foundation that provides a good introduction to writing Blender scripts in Python.

The scripting approach is fairly straight forward.  You write an *operator* class in Python to implement the operation you want, and you write a *panel* class to contain the buttons.

I'm unaware of any other approaches currently available.